# What does an equivalence between tori with $\tau$ and $\tau+1$ mean precisely?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I usually think that complex structure parameters $\tau$ and $\tau+1$ define the same complex torus (as of course do all $\tau'$ related to $\tau$ by modular transformations). I can see that the lattice points defined by two vectors are the same. But doesn't the equivalence between $\tau$ and $\tau+1$ imply that there is some kind of a holomorphic map from the parallelogram drawn on $(\tau,1)$ to a parallelogram drawn on $(\tau+1,1)$? Naively this is not possible, since the angles are clearly not preserved.

Comment: It means you are changing your symplectic basis of $H_1(E;\mathbb{Z})$.  Nothing else changes.

Comment: Conformal and thus holomorphic maps preserve angles and orientation locally.

Comment: So there doesn't have to be a holomorphic map between the two parallelograms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this equivalence does not mean there is some kind of holomorphic map between the parallelograms.

What it means is there is a holomorphic map between the two quotient tori 
$$\mathbb C \, / \, (\mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z) \quad\text{and}\quad \mathbb C \, / \, (\mathbb Z + (\tau + 1) \mathbb Z)
$$
which is completely obvious, given that the lattices $\mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z + (\tau + 1) \mathbb Z$ are identical.